# Is their any way to fetch/update specific div content of website when server is mostly in timeout state?

Tags: javascript, web, tampermonkey

Actually I have created a "tampermonkey" script that will check if specific item is available on website or not. This script refreshes the pages every 30 seconds but the server is mostly down (request timeout). So, is their any solution to solve this problem. 
One solution that I am thinking is to fetch specific div tag on reload not the whole page (I don't know it is better solution or not)?

Please tell me if their is any better solution ?

Comment: Unless the website in question offers some sort of Web-API (ReST w/e) you are out of luck my friend.

Comment: As for requesting only a <div> from server you can only request what is actually available from any given end point.

Comment: Can you please tell how to check if the website offers some sort of Web-API ?